# Ember fewer requests for hasMany and belongsTo lookups

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, handlebars.js

I have the following three models:

```
ConversationApp.Post = DS.Model.extend(
  body: DS.attr()
  replies: DS.hasMany('reply', async: true)
  author: DS.belongsTo('user', async: true)
  likedBy: DS.hasMany('user', async: true)
)

ConversationApp.Reply = DS.Model.extend(
  body: DS.attr()
  post: DS.belongsTo('post')
  author: DS.belongsTo('user', async: true)
  likedBy: DS.hasMany('user', async: true)
)

ConversationApp.User = DS.Model.extend(
  firstName: DS.attr()
  lastName: DS.attr()
)
```

And my index route makes this call:

```
ConversationApp.IndexRoute = Em.Route.extend(
  model: (args) ->
    @store.find('post', page: 1) # => /api/v1/posts?page=1
)
```

After that call is made, Ember starts fetching all the users needed for the first page - a total of 17(!) different requests for users on the first page (with 10 posts). Here are 3 examples of the requests Ember makes to the server:

- /api/v1/users/11375
- /api/v1/users/4383
- /api/v1/users?ids[]=34588&ids[]=7442&ids[]=10294

I would like Ember to only make one request, that requests all the required users for the first page:

- /api/v1/users?ids[]=34588&ids[]=7442&ids[]=10294&ids[]=11375&ids[]=4383

The handlebars file looks like this:

```
{{#each}}
  {{author.firstName}}
  {{#each likedBy}}
    [... removed for brevity ...]
  {{/each}}

  {{#each replies}}
    {{author.firstName}}
    {{#each likedBy}}
      [... removed for brevity ...]
    {{/each}}
  {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

How can I accomplish that?

Comment: Something in your code should be firing those first two requests, that usually happens when you try to access a record that is not loaded yet. It depends on how you're building your app, but for sure, there's something trying to access those two records before being loaded.

Comment: I've added the handlebars template. I think the problem is, that Ember doesnt load the users references, before they are used. Ember first loads the author, then the likedBy references for each of the posts and replies. I wonder if there's a better way to do this.

Comment: you can always check if content is loaded. for example, wrap that code in a {{#if isLoaded}}....{{/if}}, that should work.

Comment: I added {{#if isLoaded}} after {{#each}}. I still get the same number of request.

Comment: no, add it before the 'each', why looping through the data if it hasn't been loaded.

Comment: Then nothing is displayed. Ember makes the request to /api/v1/posts?page=1, but after that, nothing is displayed, and Ember doesnt request more data.

Comment: Ok, it's going to be hard to guess what your problem is. But you now know that something is firing those requests because that object is not loaded yet. One last comment, try if author.isLoaded inside the 'each'. Play with that.

Comment: That hides the content until each of the employees has loaded, but Ember still makes the same number of requests.

Comment: Perhaps you could use the ember inspector plugin for Chrome. The Promises tab might allow you to trace where each of the 3 calls is originating from.

Comment: @MartinStannard I couldnt find any useful information from the panel. Here's a screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/1FprSxg.png.

Comment: Out of curiousity, why can't you sideload those users when you retrieve the posts? This is a classic n+1 problem, you'd have this problem even you were looping over the posts with lets say ActiveRecord in a rails view.

Comment: @RyanRauh I could - and I considered adding users to the response. I opted against it, because I don't want to pollute the API. Here's the output I get from /api/v1/posts?page=1 http://i.imgur.com/xXUckhB.png. I sideload replies, because they are always needed along with the posts. The users, on the other hand, are only needed by this Ember application.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I know that this is an old thread, but here is a solution using the `DS.RESTAdapter`.

It's pretty easy to accomplish this. The only thing you have to do is set `coalesceFindRequests` to be `true`, like so:

```
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    coalesceFindRequests: true
});
```

or if you are using [Ember CLI](http://www.ember-cli.com/)

```
// app/adapters/application.js
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    coalesceFindRequests: true
});
```

You can read more about it in the [DS.RESTAdapter api docs](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTAdapter.html#property_coalesceFindRequests)

Good luck! :)

Comment: Thanks for updating this question. I'm also following the Ember improvements, and changed my code to using this method a while ago. I've updated the accepted answer for other people with the same requirements. Here's the change from the changelog: https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#ember-data-100-beta9-august-18-2014

Comment: According to the docs, it seems that `coalesceFindRequests` defaults to `true`.

Answer (score 3):

So I took a stab at this. Unfortunately, I don't believe Ember-Data provides this kind of functionality out of the box. But it doesn't seem to difficult to implement. My approach was to use a debouncer. Basically, every time a request for users is made, the request is put into a pool. The pool fills up until a long enough period has gone by (50ms in my code) without another request. After that time, the requests are all sent together and the pool is emptied. Then, when the giant request comes back, it's broken up into smaller ones that can be used to fulfill the requests that were originally in the pool.

Keep in mind, I haven't tested this yet, but this should show the general idea.

```
App.UserAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    _findMany: null,

    find: function(store, type, id) {
        return this.findMany(store, type, [id]);
    },

    findMany: function(store, type, ids) {
        this._findMany = this._super;

        // Create a promise, but keep the resolve function so we can call it later
        var resolve;
        var promise = new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(r) {
            resolve = r;
        });

        // Let our debouncer know about this request
        this.concatenateRequest(store, ids, resolve);

        // Return a promise as usual
        return promise;
    },

    /**
     * The number of milliseconds after a request to wait before sending it.
     * Tweak this as necessary for performance.
     */
    debounceTimeout: 50,

    concatenateRequest: (function() {
        // All of the IDs currently requested in the pool
        var allIds = new Em.Set();
        // The pool of promises that is currently awaiting fulfillment
        var allPromises = [];

        // The ID of the last `setTimeout` call
        var timeout = null;

        // Takes the specified users out of the payload
        // We do this to break the giant payload into the small ones that were requested
        var extractUsers = function(payload, ids) {
            // Filter out the users that weren't requested
            // Note: assuming payload = { users: [], linked: {}, meta: {} }
            var users = payload.users.filter(function(user) {
                return (ids.indexOf(user.id.toString()) >= 0);
            });

            // Return payload in form that store is expecting
            return { users: users };
        };

        return function(store, ids, resolve) {
            // clear the timeout (if it's already cleared, no effect)
            clearTimeout(timeout);

            // Add the current promise to the list of promises to resolve
            allIds.addObjects(ids);
            allPromises.push({ ids: ids, resolve: resolve });

            // Set our timeout function up in case another request doesn't come in time
            timeout = setTimeout(function() {
                // Get the IDs and promises store so far so we can resolve them
                var ids = allIds.toArray();
                var promises = allPromises;

                // Clear these so the next request doesn't resolve the same promises twice
                allIds = new Em.Set();
                allPromises = [];

                // Send off for the users we know need
                this._findMany(store, ConversationApp.User, ids).then(function(payload) {                   
                    // Resolve each promise individually
                    promises.forEach(function(promise) {
                        // extract the correct users from the payload
                        var users = extractUsers(payload, promise.ids);
                        // resolve the promise with the users it requested
                        promise.resolve(users);
                    });
                });
            }.bind(this), this.get('debounceTimeout'));
        };
    })()
});
```

EDIT: I set up a quick [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/getayive/1/) with a unit test and it seems to function OK. It's a pretty fragile test, but it shows that the idea works well enough.

Comment: Looks like it's excactly what I'm looking for. Great work! I've been trying to implement it in my project, but ran into a problem with this line: "_findMany: DS.RESTAdapter.findMany". _findMany is null. How do I get the reference to the old method?

Comment: You could change that to `DS.RESTAdapter.create().findMany`. Or you could get it from your modified `findMany`. I'll update my post with that.

Comment: I also added a modified `find` method since that example only showed overriding `findMany`.

Comment: Looks like it's almost there! And thanks for the find addition. Next problem: @_findMany(store, 'user', ids).then((payload) -> resolves to this URL: /api/v1?ids... For some reason, the user part is missing from the URL: /api/v1/users?ids...

Comment: Sorry, I'm used to my own persistence library. I used `'user'` instead of `ConversationApp.User` when calling `_findMany`. Change that and it should work.

Comment: Thank you very, very much! You taught me a few tricks here. I think that this behaviour should be in Ember, when belongsTo and/or hasMany are set as async: true.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with Ember Data, but I think it's not Ember's fault. You can try to change your JSON API to side load the associated data.

Ember Data uses [JSON API](http://jsonapi.org/format/) as the json standard. It has described the format for relationship, and how to send data and it's relationship in one request.

If everything works (in the future), in the request `/api/v1/posts`, if you want to side load all replies, you can construct json like this:

```
{
  "posts": [{
    "id": "1",
    "body": "post body 1",
    "links": {
      "replies": ["1", "2"]
    }
  }, {
    "id": "2",
    "body": "post body 2",
    "links": {
      "replies": ["3"]
    }
  }],
  "linked": {
    "replies": [{
      "id": "1",
      "body": "reply body 1"
    }, {
      "id": "2",
      "body": "reply body 2"
    }, {
      "id": "3",
      "body": "reply body 3"
    }]
  }
}
```

Unfortunately it's not working now. I checked latest Ember Data source and can't find any code  with "linked" support.

If you're using Rails and ActiveModelSerializer, another working way is to use embedded data, see this [Ember Data test](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/activemodel-adapter/tests/integration/embedded_records_mixin_test.js#L173) for the nested data format.

Both JSON API and Ember Data are unfinished projects. That means everything may change in the future, and even today Ember Data is not fully support JSON API. So if you want to use Ember Data in your real world project. You must be very familiar with it's architecture and is able to customize Adapters & Serializers for your own use.

Comment: Sideloading works fine. I use sideloading with Ember data in many projects - including this one. I actually sideload all the replies, but I dont want to sideload the users, because I don't want to pollute the API. Here's the output I get from /api/v1/posts?page=1 http://i.imgur.com/xXUckhB.png. Take a moment to read the comments above. :-)