# Ember data bulk fetch async hasMany relationship records

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, json-api

I'd like to know whether it is possible to configure Ember data in a way that async hasMany relationships are loaded in a single request.

Given the following model:

```
// models/post.js
export default DS.Model.extend({
  comments: DS.hasMany()
});

// models/comments.js
export default DS.Model.extend({
  ...
});
```

When I reference the property `comments` somewhere in the template or controller, it will fetch the related comments of the post one-by-one in separate requests. This results in many requests and I'd like to combine those into a single request with a filter on id-property.

Comment: There is a switch you'd have to set in your adapter (fe. RESTAdapter): `coalesceFindRequests: true`. This will then result in desired requests to the server: `api/comments?ids[]=1&ids[]=2`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ember fewer requests for hasMany and belongsTo lookups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21865974/ember-fewer-requests-for-hasmany-and-belongsto-lookups)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a switch you have to enable for the desired behaviour called `coalesceFindRequests: true` that you can set in you application adapter like so:

```
// adapters/application.js
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    coalesceFindRequests: true,
});
```

Now Ember will fetch multiple records of known id via `..api/comments?ids[]=1&ids[]=2`

I suppose it'll be the same for a JSONAdapter.

Comment: http://www.emberjs.com.cn/api/data/classes/DS.JSONAPIAdapter.html#property_coalesceFindRequests

Comment: Thanks! This was exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: "I suppose it'll be the same for a JSONAPIAdapter", yeah you are right. The [JSONAPIAdapter](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/v3.0.0/addon/adapters/json-api.js) also has the `coalesceFindRequests` property. I thought it was supposed to be `true` as default value, but currently it's still `false`. So  you need to enable it yourself, if you want to use this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should use link relationships:

Instead of this:

```
relationships: {
    commend: {
        data: [
            { id: '1', type: 'comment' },
            { id: '2', type: 'comment' }
        ]
    }
}
```

do this:

```
relationships: {
    comments: {
        links: {
            related: 'http://example.com/post/A/comments'
        }
    }
}
```

The nice thing about this is that you can 100% adjust this in your backend.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. What if most of the related `comments` are already in the client store? Then it will refetch the data. I'd like to see a solution in (maybe) an ember adapter where it detects that multiple resources of the same model has to be queried, it then combines the ids in a single request without fetching to many records, e.g.: `/api/comments/?id=1,3,23`